# why android studio gradle download sources location with /sources/ segment? but, nexus maven has no /sources/ in path, so not match

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus

download sources:

http:///nexus/content/groups/public/com/netease/edu/android/lib-module-browser/***sources***/lib-module-browser-1.5.3-sources.jar

maven:

http:///nexus/content/groups/public/com/netease/edu/android/lib-module-browser/1.5.3/lib-module-browser-1.5.3-sources.jar

Q：how to remove /source/ , make there match?